# Debugging php object instantiation

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I am using ajax to call a php script (wordpress). I get status code `200 OK` but I dont get any data back.. My script dies, when trying to create an instant of an object. But I cant get any info why..

```
// create Order object
echo "this gets returned";
try {
   if(new Order($auth_login, $auth_password, $caleo_live_mode)) {
       echo "works";
    } else {
        echo "if error";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "try fail";
}
echo "This does not";
```

Nothing inside the `try` block is getting returned.

What can I do to try to see what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> ANSWER: 
>   I figured it out....
>
> I read through the source code of `Order` and found a `try/catch` statement which looked like:
>
> ```
> catch (Exception $e) {
>     exit();
> }
> ```